# How to pass variable parameters via the pipeline?

Tags: powershell

I'm putting together a PS Module that talks to a REST API for some software that I work with.

I have `Add-Object`, `Search-Object` and `Remove-Object` cmdLets that all work well in isolation, but I'm struggling to get them to work together via the pipeline in the way that I'd like.

So for example, if I want to search for an object and then delete the search results, I have to do it like so:

```
Search-Object -target $targetAddress `
              -AuthenticationToken $authtoken `
              -Query "Test Object" `
| Remove-Object -target $targetAddress `
                -AuthenticationToken $authtoken
```

The output of the `Search-Object` cmdLet is successfully passed via the pipeline but the `Target` and `AuthenticationToken` variables are not.

If I remove them from the `Remove-Object` cmdLet it fails. How do I achieve this?

**Edit**:

```
[parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,
ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]$Target,

[parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,
ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]$AuthenticationToken,

[parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,
ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[ValidateLength(1,28)][string]$ObjectName
```

Comment: Please show `Remove-Object`'s parameter definitions. Also, pipeline should be processed in the `PROCESS` code block.

Comment: [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)][string]$Target,
        
  
  [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)][string]$AuthenticationToken,
        
  
  [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)][ValidateLength(1,28)][string]$ObjectName

Comment: I am using the PROCESS block to perform everything the cmdLet does.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ValueFromPipeline=$true`declarations from your parameter definitions, and only use `ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName`. If you use both declarations, the function translates a string representation of the whole object for each parameter, instead of the values of the named properties. `ValueFromPipeline` should be used if you except objects of known type from pipe as a single parameter. Now you are asking for named `String`s and this will work:

```
[parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]$Target,
[parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[string]$AuthenticationToken,
[parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)]
[ValidateLength(1,28)][string]$ObjectName
```

**Edit:** Also make sure `Search-Object` returns objects with mandatory properties `Target`, `AuthenticationToken` and `ObjectName`. You can even feed some test objects to the `Remove-Object` to make sure it is accepting correct parameters, and the issue is in `Search-Object`:

```
$test = New-Object psobject -Property @{ "Target"="Test Target"; "AuthenticationToken"="Test Token"; "ObjectName"="Test Object" }
$test | Remove-Object
```

Comment: This fails with the error: Remove-Object : The input object cannot be bound because it did not contain the information required to bind all mandatory parameters: Target AuthenticationToken

Comment: What does following command show? `Search-Object -target $targetAddress -AuthenticationToken $authtoken -Query "Test Object" | Get-Member`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the syntax you desire is this:

```
Search-Object -target $targetAddress `
              -AuthenticationToken $authtoken `
              -Query "Test Object" | 
    Remove-Object 
        <# -target read from pipelined object property #>
        <# -AuthenticationToken read from pipelined object property#>
```

In order for `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true` to work, the objects pipelined between cmdlets must have property names that match the parameter name.

You pass `-target` to your `Search-Object` cmdlet and the `Remove-Object` cmdlet needs to find `target` and `AuthenticationToken` properties on pipelined objects it reads. Is this the case?

Try checking with:

```
Search-Object -target $targetAddress `
          -AuthenticationToken $authtoken `
          -Query "Test Object" ` | Get-Member Target,AuthenticationToken
```

Though... it feels wrong to duplicate your `AuthenticationToken` across every object returned by `Search-Object`. There may be a better way of communicating the token between cmdlets, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: This returns nothing. I can add the Target and AuthenticationToken values to the PSObject returned by Search-Object, but yeah that feels a bit wrong somehow.